# 2 validators validate one at a time

Tags: asp.net, validation

Hi I have a change password page.

I have 2 `textboxes`, `New Password` and `Confirm Password`.

Both have a `requiredFieldValidators`.

And a `compareValidator`.

But what happens is when I key in the first field `New Password`, the second textbox's `requiredFieldValidator` and `CompareValidator` are showing error messages at the same time.

I only want to show `requiredFieldValidator` and only when that validator returns true, I want to validate `compareValidator`.

How can I achieve that. The following is my code.

```
        <table class="editAccTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    New Password<br />                      
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="204px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNewPwd" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtNewPwd"
                    ValidationGroup="vgChangePwd"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Confirm New Password<br />                      
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="204px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvConfPwd" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtConfPwd"
                    ValidationGroup="vgChangePwd"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvChangePwd" runat="server"
                    ValidationGroup="vgChangePwd"
                    ControlToValidate="txtNewPwd"
                    ControlToCompare="txtConfPwd"
                    ValueToCompare="String"  
                    Display="Dynamic"                      
                    ></asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnPwdChange" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="/images/submit.jpg" onclick="ibtnPwdChange_Click" 
                    ValidationGroup="vgChangePwd" 
                    Width="90px" Height="36px"
                    />
                    <br />      
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSuccessPwdChange" runat="server"></asp:Label>             
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of work around.

For my case, I can remove the `requiredFieldValidator` for the second textbox as it is enough to have only `compareValidator`.

But there will be some cases, that there must have 2 validators. In that case, we can use `css` to overlap the 2 validators.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CompareValidator` like this

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="cvChangePwd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConfPwd"   ControlToCompare="txtNewPwd" ErrorMessage="Your passwords do not match up!" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set display property as dynamic

display="dynamic" in all the validators

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.